# Specific Branch To Git Remote

Tags: git

I want to use remote branch that is used by only one branch called development

Is this correct:

```
 $ git remote add production git@myserver.com:mywebsite.git
 $ git push production +development:refs/heads/development
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a local branch, that you want to push to the repository at `myserver.com:mywebsite.git`?

You've added the remote, but all you need to do so far as pushing is concerned is

```
$ git push production development
```

Comment: There is bare repo on mywebsite.com. And i want link a none-master branch to this repo. i am looking for appropriate command of +master:refs/heads/master.